# Typescript type-fest not working on constant

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

I am using a `PartialDeep` from [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-festhttps://), on a `const` like this:

```
const test = {
  value: 1,
  secondLevel: {
    value: 1,
    thirdLvl: {
      value: 1,
      fifthLvl: {
        value: 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I would have something like this:

```
type PD = {
  value?: number;
  secondLevel?: {
    value?: number;
    thirdLvl?: {
      value?: number;
      fifthLvl?: {
        value?: number
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But always getting only 1 deep optional properties.

Can someone explain it, or provide some workaround solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's working fine.

One thing to note is how this type displays itself. You are probably seeing something like:

```
type TestType = {
    value?: number | undefined;
    secondLevel?: PartialObjectDeep<{
        value: number;
        thirdLvl: {
            value: number;
            fifthLvl: {
                value: number;
            };
        };
    }> | undefined;
}
```

It may look like the second level does not have optional properties, however you will also see the second level is also wrapped by `PartialObjectDeep<...>`, which enforces the partial at that level.

If you try to use this type, you'll see it works just as your expect:

```
// Works fine, no errors
const testPartial: PartialDeep<typeof test> = {
  value: 1,
  secondLevel: {
    thirdLvl: {
      value: 1
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-U9GHPVcrxvTdt3yPs32XYAoO-Vc-0Ql9+zA-cRwgAAKIinjIqIbiuTZGByABtABdABKcoynFTxGCWRhGMXL0xQlKVmFAuMhwTQjoQAKzoMBFwbPAAHlZkk2g11dd1QLYjjFkYS00CcAAqPT0FHHBjg2HAfAAA1kl0MgswtZnwSAcFoTF0nJCBvwgCymwsnwdQOTYfE+dJHJgJ4IGnM01kYPAVi4fJMy0DwvOs9cLKedA9McdBPmgaQtGcpl32AJs-3be8gMIXtwNEnxL1S11yp3QsGtbbsqp3MokAcMYDKMkyzMs1r0jsuZHM2FyMnczyLNXXzAqLRgQvJcLIrymLgDi4AEt8ZKrOKtKMrQLKcqi-LCqXZ0sNUsoCLHCdhqjLqescPq0GM0yFv2tC0vs8bnNc6aYJyLyMOBny-KCpbQtWs6Nq2nakszb7nUOzLsrQXK1gKzFLqSMHz1KxqAILSrKx3GrD2PaDCdTTJHqa5CWoO112vJ5DntGV7DPegavuG0aHKcya3J8GaCZyObIcW5awoiuHYtWbaSyRlKWdso6Tsxs6caKtCJeu1t3UpwiDYe9WsndTndN6nmPsGtWfqJQX-pFoHzy8iSpPm8yZZh+X1sV+KVb2gXNYxxk8fkxSpL-BSlLAKsTbFmPlI9RRa1oxmNk+CBPFzQoIHjqSq3okN4gtzJi+Uqss5JkB6JrSwdPQIA)